# Xcode Leaks - Failed to attach to target process

Tags: xcode

I am trying to profile a C/C++ app in Xcode. I pressed Command + I for profiling, chose Leaks and then hit the record button. However, I receive this error:

```
Failed to attach to target process

Failed to execute loader thread for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/liboainject.dylib in target; target process <pid> likely exited
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I get the same error trying to profile my code using leaks.

Comment: @GianniCrivello unfortunately not :(

Answer (score -1):

check definition of your main function，use

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

instead of

```
int main()
```